# Want to create splash screen programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios-simulator

I want to create splash screen by programmatically.

But it doesn't show splash screen.

Please refer below code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIImage *aSplashImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Splash.jpeg"];
    UIImageView *aSplashImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.frame];
    aSplashImageView.image = aSplashImage;

    UIView *aSplashView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.window.frame];
    [aSplashView addSubview:aSplashImageView];

    [self.window addSubview:aSplashView];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: what do you see ? Also please add         [window makeKeyAndVisible];

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show a view as a splash screen in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984289/show-a-view-as-a-splash-screen-in-didfinishlaunchingwithoptions)

Comment: @KunalBalani : I have added the same but i can't see splash screen. Any more suggestion ?

Comment: why would you want to slow the user down?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that just adding a `UIView` to the window isnt enough, the window can already contain a `UIViewController`. And maybe your `UIView` will land behind it.

This post has some pointers how to create a splash screen: [Show a view as a splash screen in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984289/show-a-view-as-a-splash-screen-in-didfinishlaunchingwithoptions?rq=1)